# PL/SQL Comparing collections

Tags: collections, plsql, compare

I'm trying to create a function that compares 2 collections with each other. Let me explain what I'm trying to do first: I have a table for accounts and a table with teachers. I want to use this function to see if there are any accounts that aren't linked to a teacher and delete them. I have most of the function done, but I can't seem to figure out how to delete the account that isn't linked from the database. Does anyone have any ideas? Here's my code:

```
declare

type type_coll_accnr is table of account.account_id%type;
type type_coll_teachernr is table of teacher.teacher_id%type;

t_teachernr type_coll_teachernr;
t_accnr type_coll_accnr;

begin

select account_account_id
bulk collect into t_teachernr
from teacher;

select account_id
bulk collect into t_accnr
from account
where acces = 'Teacher';

for i_counter IN 1 .. t_teachernr.count
loop
if t_teachernr(i_counter) member of t_accnr then
dbms_output.put_line(t_accnr(i_counter));
else
delete from account where account_id = t_accnr(i_counter);
-- It should delete the account here, but I have no clue how.
end if;
end loop;

end;
```

I had to translate all of this, so please let me know if I missed something. I'm also pretty new to PL/SQL, so I know this might look like a stupid question!

Comment: Can't see any problems in your code. Did you execute it? Got any errors?

Comment: I run it, with some dbms_output.put_line's everywhere to check it, and it works just fine. It just doesn't delete it from the database

Comment: Well, it works for me. You said, that you need find out if account linked to teacher. I think in that case your loop should be on t_accnr list. And it should checks if current value from t_accnr is member of t_teachernr. Maybe it is the problem?

Comment: I can't do that, gives me an 'Subscript beyond count' error. Because the t_accnr collection is larger than the t_teachernr collection... Any way to work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I was right - loop should be on t_accnr list. And it should checks if current value from t_accnr is member of t_teachernr. 
I create tables and checked it. 
t_accnr is large, but it is not a problem

```
declare

type type_coll_accnr is table of account.account_id%type;
type type_coll_teachernr is table of teacher.teacher_id%type;

t_teachernr type_coll_teachernr;
t_accnr type_coll_accnr;

begin

select account_account_id
bulk collect into t_teachernr
from teacher;

select account_id
bulk collect into t_accnr
from account where acces = 'Teacher';

for i_counter IN 1 .. t_accnr.count
loop
if t_accnr(i_counter) member of t_teachernr then
dbms_output.put_line(t_accnr(i_counter));
else
dbms_output.put_line('delete from account where account_id ='|| t_accnr(i_counter));
delete from account where account_id = t_accnr(i_counter);
-- It should delete the account here, but I have no clue how.
end if;
end loop;

end;
```

Hope it helps